# When gravitational waves pass through a star or gas cloud do they cause mixing of plasma and gas?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, star-systems, nebulae

Does the compression and stretching of space stir up molecules and atoms?

Comment: The compression of space is extremely weak, so no.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Please don't answer in comments.  Write  an actual answer that can be voted on and possibly accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

The strain of typical gravitational waves from black hole mergers is on the order of $10^{-21}$. This means that a length of 1000km is compressed and stretched by about the size of one proton.

That is absolutely minute. There is no significant or measurable "mixing", or "stirring up".

If you are much closer to the source of the wave, so that they have a significant macroscopic effect, gravitational waves are not your main problem (your main problem is that you are about to fall into a black hole)

Comment: Interestingly, this would mean that a large atomic nucleus like uranium would stretch by a Planck length for a strain of 10^-21. If the Planck length is the smallest possible distance a proton at one femtometre diameter wouldn't  stretch . Quantum gravity of some kind!

Comment: @Dave Please see [Does the Planck scale imply that spacetime is discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/123208) & [Is the Planck length the smallest length that exists in the universe or is it the smallest length that can be observed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185939/123208)